# Extract a key from an Association?

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

I have some large nested expression containing associations and I'd like to extract the nth key inside one of them, using part syntax.

Here's a tiny example:

```
a = {1, <|w->x, b->{y,z}|>};
```

I'd like to extract the first key using ***part syntax***, is it even possible without using functions like `Query` or `PositionIndex`or `Normal` or `Keys`?

```
a[[2, ?]] == w
```

Comment: I think `Query` is the best fit.  Something like `Query[2, Keys /* {1}]@a`

Comment: As a short answer: no, you cannot extract keys using `Part` syntax. `Part` can only extract values. You can use keys as `Part` specifications, but you will always get values out.

Comment: Maybe `a // PositionIndex[#[[2]]][[1]] &` ?

Comment: To put it more bluntly than Sjoerd: `Association`s are **atomic** objects and are not even meant to be accessed with `Part` in the traditional sense. In my interpretation, `Part` was specially overloaded for `Association`.

Comment: You can do this as `First @ Keys @ a[[2, {1}]]`, where the heavy lifting is still done by `Part`. By wrapping the last position in a List, we tell the Part that we want to preserve the head, which is an assoc, so you get back <|w -> x|>. This should generalize to any other such case you want. This is similar to the suggestion of @Edmund, except that we don't have the overhead of `Query`.

Comment: @Edmund would you like to sum up comments in an answer? :)